# C++ show me how stop this while infintie loop

Tags: c++

I get an infinite loop when user does not enter a number. I have tried hours and can not get it to stop i am new to this so if you can please help  me stop the infinite loop i would be thankful. The infinite loop seem to only happen when user enters something that is not a number.

```
// libraries to add that are required for this program with 
// identification of what library gives what objects
#include <iostream>             // provides:  cout, cin
#include <iomanip>              // provides:  setw setprecision(n)
#include <limits>


// setting up the environment
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    // usimg Window.h
    // Print out title of program
    cout << " - GPA Calculation Program - \n";

    string str; // Gets User inpit

    // Give 2 lines spacing
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    // list of variables needed
    const double max = 100;   // constant variable for max grade = 100
    const double min = 0;     // constant variable for min grade = 0
    const double Hours = 3;  // constant variable for Credit Hours = 3

    int gradeNum = 0;         //  variable for Grade #
    double grade;             //  variable for Grade input by user 
    double GPA;               //  variable for value of GPA points varys by user inputs for grade

    bool True1 = true;        //  bool statement for True
    bool True2 = true;        //  bool statement for True
    bool True3 = true;        //  bool statement for True
    bool True4 = true;        //  bool statement for True

    double Total = 0.0;       //  variable for adding all of the        Total_GPA_multiply_HOURS together
    double  TotalGpa = 0.0;   //  variable for adding all of gpa together
    double gpa = 0.0;         //  variable for value of GPA being incremented 
    double  Total_GPA_multiply_HOURS = 0.0;   //  variable for value of results of  GPA * Hours

    // start a while loop  Asking user for input and give them response
    while (True1 == true)
    {
        gradeNum++;              // Grade number is increased by 1 for each user entry
        True4 = true;             // Turn switch 4 on

        while (True4 == true)
        { // start of 4th while loop

            bool True2 = true;        //  bool statement for True

            //Prints   to the console the question  the the user will answer with a number that represents their grade

            cout << "Enter Grade " << gradeNum << " (From 0 to 100): ";

            cin >> grade;

            while (True2 == true)
            {// start of 2nd while loop 

                if (grade >= 90 && grade <= max)
                { //  start 1st if

                    // prints Letter grade for user input if statements true
                    //  and does calculations to get the user GPA

                    cout << "Your letter grade is A \n";
                    GPA = 4;
                    gpa += 4;
                    Total_GPA_multiply_HOURS = GPA * Hours;
                    True2 = false;
                    True4 = false;
                    True3 = true;
                    True3 = true;
                }

                else if (grade >= 80 && grade <90)
                {
                    // prints Letter grade for user input if statements true
                    //  and does calculations to get the user GPA

                    cout << "Your letter grade is B \n";
                    GPA = 3;
                    gpa += 3;
                    Total_GPA_multiply_HOURS = GPA * Hours;
                    True2 = false;
                    True4 = false;
                    True3 = true;
                    True3 = true;
                }

                else if (grade >= 70 && grade <80)
                {
                    // prints Letter grade for user input if statements true
                    //  and does calculations to get the user GPA

                    cout << "Your letter grade is C \n\n";
                    GPA = 3;
                    gpa += 3;
                    Total_GPA_multiply_HOURS = GPA * Hours;
                    True2 = false;
                    True4 = false;
                    True3 = true;
                    True3 = true;
                }

                else if (grade >= 60 && grade <70)
                {
                    // prints Letter grade for user input if statements true
                    //  and does calculations to get the user GPA     

                    cout << "Your letter grade is D \n\n";
                    GPA = 2;
                    gpa += 2;
                    Total_GPA_multiply_HOURS = GPA * Hours;
                    True2 = false;
                    True4 = false;
                    True3 = true;
                    True3 = true;
                }

                else  if (grade >= min && grade <60)
                {
                    // prints Letter grade for user input if statements true
                    //  and does calculations to get the user GPA

                    cout << "Your letter grade is F \n\n";

                    GPA = 0;
                    gpa += 0;
                    Total_GPA_multiply_HOURS = GPA * Hours;
                    True2 = false;
                    True4 = false;
                    True3 = true;
                    True3 = true;
                }

                else if ((grade < min || grade > max) && (grade > -100000000 && grade < 100000000))
                {
                    // print error for invalid entry   

                    cout << "*** ERROR: " << grade << " is INVALID grade\n" << " Grade must be from 0 to 100! \n \n PLease enter a Grade and has to be from 0 to 100!\n\n\n";


                    True2 = false;
                    True4 = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    // print error for invalid entry   

                    cout << "*** ERROR: The input you have provided is not a number!\n Please enter a number from 1 to 100!\n\n\n";

                    cin.fail();
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

                    True1 = false;
                    True2 = false;
                    True3 = false;
                    True4 = false;


                } //  end of 1st if


            } // end of 2nd while loop


        }// end  4th while loop
    }// end 1st while loop

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not post that much code, but an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) instead.

Comment: and please *format* your code properly in order to make it readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> I get an infinite loop when user does not enter a number

Create a function that prints the prompt, tries to read the number, if reading doesn't succeed, clears the input stream and calls itself again.

```
double readGrade(int gradeNum)
{
    double grade;
    cout << "Enter Grade " << gradeNum <<" (From 0 to 100): ";
    if ( !(cin >> grade) )
    {
       // Clear the stream.
       cin.clear();

       // Discard everything up to the newline.
       cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

       // Call the function again.
       return readGrade(gradeNum);
    }

    return grade;
}
```

Then, replace the following lines in main

```
cout << "Enter Grade " << gradeNum <<" (From 0 to 100): ";

cin >> grade;
```

by a call to `readGrade()`.

```
grade = readGrade(gradeNum);
```

Comment: Thank you so much i figured it out with your help thank you and sorry for the post quality this was my first time. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

I have tweaked your GPA program in multiple places:

1. added 2 varialbes to keep track of the subject being taken as input and to set a maximum number of subjects of 10.

   ```
   int maxSubjects = 10;
   int currentSubject = 0;
   ```
2. Then checked condition `(currentSubject < maxSubjects)` to make sure
   number of subjects are not exceeded.
3. Changed calculation from `Total_GPA_multiply_HOURS = GPA * Hours;` to     `Total_GPA_multiply_HOURS += GPA * Hours;`, as we needed this value to get the persons actual GPA after getting input of all values.
4. Added a condition after the inner while loop to ensure outer while
   loop is exited when 10 subjects are entered

   ```
   if (currentSubject == maxSubjects){
       break;
   }
   ```
5. Added a line to print out the calculated GPA, `cout << "GPA: " << (Total_GPA_multiply_HOURS/gpa) << endl;`

Here is the complete program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << " - GPA Calculation Program -" << endl << endl << endl;
    string str;
    const double max = 100;
    const double min = 0;
    const double Hours = 3;
    int maxSubjects = 10;
    int currentSubject = 0;

    int gradeNum = 0;
    double grade;
    double GPA;

    bool True1 = true;
    bool True2 = true;
    bool True3 = true;
    bool True4 = true;

    double Total = 0.0;
    double  TotalGpa = 0.0;
    double gpa = 0.0;
    double  Total_GPA_multiply_HOURS = 0.0;

    while (True1 == true)
    {
        gradeNum++;
        True4 = true;
        currentSubject++;
        while (True4 == true && (currentSubject < maxSubjects))
        {
            True2 = true;
            cout << "Enter Grade " << gradeNum << " (From 0 to 100): ";
            cin >> grade;
            while (True2 == true)
            {
                if (grade >= 90 && grade <= max)
                {
                    cout << "Your letter grade is A \n";
                    GPA = 4;
                    gpa += 4;
                    Total_GPA_multiply_HOURS += GPA * Hours;
                    True2 = false;
                    True4 = false;
                    True3 = true;
                }
                else if (grade >= 80 && grade <90)
                {
                    cout << "Your letter grade is B \n";
                    GPA = 3;
                    gpa += 3;
                    Total_GPA_multiply_HOURS += GPA * Hours;
                    True2 = false;
                    True4 = false;
                    True3 = true;
                }
                else if (grade >= 70 && grade <80)
                {
                    cout << "Your letter grade is C \n\n";
                    GPA = 3;
                    gpa += 3;
                    Total_GPA_multiply_HOURS += GPA * Hours;
                    True2 = false;
                    True4 = false;
                    True3 = true;
                }
                else if (grade >= 60 && grade <70)
                {
                    cout << "Your letter grade is D \n\n";
                    GPA = 2;
                    gpa += 2;
                    Total_GPA_multiply_HOURS += GPA * Hours;
                    True2 = false;
                    True4 = false;
                    True3 = true;
                }
                else  if (grade >= min && grade <60)
                {
                    cout << "Your letter grade is F \n\n";
                    GPA = 0;
                    gpa += 0;
                    Total_GPA_multiply_HOURS += GPA * Hours;
                    True2 = false;
                    True4 = false;
                    True3 = true;
                }
                else if ((grade < min || grade > max) && (grade > -100000000 && grade < 100000000))
                {
                    cout << "*** ERROR: " << grade << " is INVALID grade\n" << " Grade must be from 0 to 100! \n \n PLease enter a Grade and has to be from 0 to 100!\n\n\n";
                    True2 = false;
                    True4 = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "*** ERROR: The input you have provided is not a number!\n Please enter a number from 1 to 100!\n\n\n";
                    cin.fail();
                    cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                    True1 = false;
                    True2 = false;
                    True3 = false;
                    True4 = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (currentSubject == maxSubjects){
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "GPA: " << (Total_GPA_multiply_HOURS/gpa) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.